# Javascript - emulating chrome-debugger's element highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ace-editor

I wonder if anyone has ever done something like that - 
I would like to be able to emulate the ability of chrome debugger (or any other browser debugger) to highlight a rendered element by hovering/selecting its code equivalent element.

for example, I have the following layout:

[image]

the top part is an iframe element which renders a sample HTML page, and the bottom part is an embedded in-browser code editor ([ace](https://ace.c9.io/)), which displays the HTML code of the iframe's contents. I would like to be able to highlight an HTML element inside the iframe by hovering its corresponding HTML code element in the code editor.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve something like that? I would like to hear some interesting directions.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I thought

> Inspect element

in Google Chrome could do the job

**How to use Inspect Element**

Right click on any website and click the last one **Inspect element** (and wait for a while).

Then the developer tools is going to popup with html. You can hover the mouse on those code in developer tools and it would highlight the website element as you hover and those color which highlight is different for indicate padding, margin and element itself.

More than those function you also do a lot with chrome developer tools such as editing styles and DOM, check your CSS class, check your size

**For further information**

**[This is official site](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/dom-and-styles#inspecting-elements)**.

If you want to reverse Chrome
[Chrome DevTools App](https://github.com/auchenberg/chrome-devtools-app)

Comment: I would like to emulate this functionality

Comment: @royv So you should approach the emulation with reverse engineering Google Chrome. I will add useful link for that in the answer.